# Не менять цвет QPushButton при установке disabled

Tags: c++, qt5

Если кнопке `QPushButton` установить `setDisabled(true)` то текст\картинка установленная на поверхности кнопки обесцветится. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться со стилем. Я из любопытства добавил стиль `QPushButton[enabled=false] {color:"red"; background-color:"blue"}` (прямо в Дизайнере, но setStyle тоже заработает) и отключил enable - сработало. Осталось только ипользовать системную цветовую схему

Comment: P.S. Изменил стиль на `QPushButton[enabled=false] {color:"black";}` (не мудрствуя лукаво) и отключеная кнопка внешне не отличается от включенной.

Comment: @asianirish прописываю эту строку в .qss но никакой реакции - как будто не понимают команду.

Comment: @Andrej_Levkovitch я делал изменения в т.н. 'Design Mode' в qtcreator'е. Тоже самое можено сделать и через .cpp. Кстати, в 'Design Mode' можно также можно изменить палитру (проперция palette->Change Palette->Show Details->ButtonText (сменить в столбике Disabled на черный). Результат можно посмотреть в Preview->Disabled.

Comment: @asianirish странно, но через .qss так не работает. Да и синтаксис странный: если я все правильно понял, то [enabled = false] тоже что и !enabled - тоесть задается цвет для кнопки, которая не в enabled статусе, но при disabled это не играет роли, так как все обесцвечивается и становится серым. Или я не верно все понял?

Comment: @Andrej_Levkovitch я не большой специалист в имплиминтации css для qt. Возможно парсинг кода css в .qss отличается от парсинга непосредственно в ui (возможно распознает только "чистый" css, или использует другой синтаксис для кнопок). Стыдно признаться, но я даже ни разу не добавлял файл .qss и не связывал его с формой и даже не знаю, как это сделать (возможно речь идет о новой версии qtcreator'а(?)). Чем мог, помог. У меня заработало

Comment: @asianirish и на том спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того что б дизэйблить кнопку, задисконнекть ее сигнал от слота, на который у тебя коннект ссылается. Для этой цели хорошо вместо автоматического on_foo_clicked() руками прописать слот onFooClicked() <именно без подчеркиваний>, и коннектить-дисконнектить его руками. Например, коннектить его в конструкторе

```
QObject::connect(ui.foo, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onFooClicked()))
```

и в том месте, где ты заново будешь включать кнопку,и дисконнектить

```
QObject::disconnect(ui.foo, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onFooClicked()))
```

там, где ты сейчас хочешь ее задизэйблить.

Comment: Проблема не в сигнале, а в состоянии кнопки. Даже если разорвать коннект она все равно будет нажиматься - в этом проблема, а не в сигнале. Если бы проблема была в сигнале, я бы просто написал бы лямбду с проверкой условия - это было бы эффективнее.